# A006517: Numbers with $n\mid 2^n+2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Problem 323 from the IMO 2009 reads:

*Prove that there are infinitely many positive integers n such that $2^n+2$ is divisible by $n$*.

An amazingly nice (and short) solution can be found [here](http://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v14_n2.pdf) (see page 3).

OEIS sequence [A006517](http://oeis.org/A006517) lists the 27 smallest integers $n$ with $n\mid 2^n+2$:
  $$ 1, 2, 6, 66, 946, 8646, 180246, 199606, 265826, 383846, 1234806, 3757426, 9880278, 14304466, 23612226, 27052806, 43091686, 63265474, 66154726, 69410706, 81517766, 106047766, 129773526, 130520566, 149497986, 184416166, 279383126. $$

All these numbers, with the exception of $1$, are even, and Max Alekseyev [has shown](http://oeis.org/A006517) that this keeps to hold for larger terms, too: if $n\mid 2^n+2$ and $n>1$, then $n$ is even.

Yet another observation is that all numbers listed above are square-free. Does this hold in general?

> Is it true that if $n\mid 2^n+2$, then $n$ is square-free?

---

(Also posted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/326123/9924)

Comment: A not squarefree example must exceed $\large 10^{15}$

Comment: Still no not squarefree solution upto $\large 10^{16}$

Comment: @Peter: We know that a counterexample must be divisible by $2p^2$, where $p$ is a Wieferich prime. On the other hand, $2^n\equiv -2\pmod p$, along with the fact that $n$ is even, shows that any odd prime $p$ dividing $n$ satisfies $(-2/p)=1$. Since there are only two Wieferich primes below $10^{17}$, and none of them satisfies this condition, any counterexample must exceed $2\cdot 10^{34}$.

Comment: Good observation !

Comment: What does $(-2/p)=1$ mean?

Comment: @mbjoe: the Legendre symbol, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol.

Comment: @W-t-P could you explain why that holds? Thank you.

Comment: @mbjoe: $-2\equiv 2^n\pmod p$, and $n$ is even; that is, $-2$ is a square (quadratic residue) in mod $p$.

Comment: Now posted also on MO: [A006517: Integers with $n\mid 2^n+2$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/326123).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks for doing the job for me :-)

Comment: @W-t-P Well, I'd guess that including link directly into the post would give it more visibility. [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives, in my opinion, very reasonable recommendations regarding [meta-tag:cross-posting].

Answer (score 3):

**Just an observation**. If we assume $n=q\cdot p^2$ where $p$ is an odd prime number, then
$$2^{n} \equiv -2 \pmod{p^2} \tag{1}$$
and from [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)
$$2^{\varphi\left(p^2\right)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2} \iff
2^{p(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2} \tag{2}$$
Expanding $(2)$ we have
$$2^{p^2(p-1)} \equiv 1^p \pmod{p^2} \Rightarrow 
2^{q\cdot p^2 \cdot (p-1)} \equiv 1^q \pmod{p^2} \Rightarrow \\
2^{n \cdot (p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2} \tag{3}$$
but, from $(1)$ and given $p-1$ is even
$$2^{n\cdot(p-1)} \equiv (-2)^{p-1} \equiv 2^{p-1} \pmod{p^2} \tag{4}$$
combining $(3)$ and $(4)$
$$2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$$
which makes $p$ a [Wieferich prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime) (also [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1963-17-082/S0025-5718-1963-0159780-0/S0025-5718-1963-0159780-0.pdf)), of which only two are known so far, $1093$ and $3511$ ([A001220](https://oeis.org/A001220)).

Comment: I found that out independent from your post (+1). I did not find a squarefree example yet, but it must be greater than $10^{13}$. One slight remark : $n$ cannot be divisible by $4$, so we actually can conclude that $p^2\mid n$ is only possible for odd prime $p$

Comment: @rtybase: Good point!